# Get a class from a type scala

Tags: scala

In scala, I want to be able to say

`val user = Node.create[User](...) // return User object`

So here's what I have so far:

```
def create[T : TypeTag](map: Map[String, Any]) {
    val type = typeOf[T]
    // create class from type here???
}
```

I've been digging around how to create classes from generic types and found out that using ClassManifest seems to be deprecated. Instead, type tags are here, so I'm able to do something like this typeOf[T] and actually get the type.. but then I'm lost. If I could get the class, then I could use something like class.newInstance and manually set the fields from there.

Question is: given a type, can I get a class instance of the given type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way in fact is to use [`ClassTag`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag):

```
def create[T : ClassTag](map: Map[String, Any]): T = {
  val clazz: Class[_] = classTag[T].runtimeClass
  clazz.newInstance(<constructor arguments here>).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

`ClassTag` is a thin wrapper around Java `Class`, primarily used for arrays instantiation.

`TypeTag` facility is more powerful. First, you can use it to invoke Java reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def create[T: TypeTag](map: Map[String, Any]): T = {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)  // current class classloader
  val clazz: Class[_] = mirror.runtimeClass(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass)
  clazz.newInstance(<constructor arguments here>).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

However, Scala reflection allows to instantiate classes without dropping back to Java reflection:

```
def create[T: TypeTag](map: Map[String, Any]): T = {
  // obtain type symbol for the class, it is like Class but for Scala types
  val typeSym = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass

  // obtain class mirror using runtime mirror for the given classloader
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)  // current class classloader
  val cm = mirror.reflectClass(typeSym)

  // resolve class constructor using class mirror and 
  // a constructor declaration on the type symbol
  val ctor = typeSym.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  val ctorm = cm.reflectConstructor(cm)

  // invoke the constructor
  ctorm(<constructor arguments here>).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

If you want to create a class with overloaded constructors, it may require more work though - you'll have to select correct constructor from declarations list, but the basic idea is the same. You can read more on Scala reflection [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with reflection: either runtime reflection, or in a macro. Regarding runtime reflection way, you can have a look at [my blog post](http://anaivecoder.blogspot.nl/2013_07_01_archive.html) where I tried to do something like what you are trying to do now. Using compile-time reflection with macros might be a better option, depending on your need.